# Hi i am new to React js can you help me convert this class component to functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, functional-programming, components

hello this is the code below , how to convert this class component to functional component in React js.
Hi i am new to React js can you help me convert this class component to functional component.i am trying to create a button which clicked should generate a pdf using jspdf and jspdf autotable

```
    import React from 'react';
    import jsPDF from "jspdf";
    import "jspdf-autotable";
    import './App.css';
    
    class App extends React. Component {
    
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          people: [
            { name: "Keanu Reeves", profession: "Actor" },
            { name: "Lionel Messi", profession: "Football Player" },
            { name: "Cristiano Ronaldo", profession: "Football Player" },
            { name: "Jack Nicklaus", profession: "Golf Player" },
          ]
        }
      }
    
      exportPDF = () => {
        const unit = "pt";
        const size = "A4"; // Use A1, A2, A3 or A4
        const orientation = "portrait"; // portrait or landscape
    
        const marginLeft = 40;
        const doc = new jsPDF(orientation, unit, size);
    
        doc.setFontSize(15);
    
        const title = "My Awesome Report";
        const headers = [["NAME", "PROFESSION"]];
    
        const data = this.state.people.map(elt=> [elt.name, elt.profession]);
    
        let content = {
          startY: 50,
          head: headers,
          body: data
        };
    
        doc.text(title, marginLeft, 40);
        doc.autoTable(content);
        doc.save("report.pdf")
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => this.exportPDF()}>Generate Report</button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: please update your question with any attempts you have made

Comment: const [exportPDF, setExportPDF] = useState(true);

Comment: exportPDF = () => {
  const unit = "pt";
  const size = "A4"; // Use A1, A2, A3 or A4
  const orientation = "portrait"; // portrait or landscape

  const marginLeft = 40;
  const doc = new jsPDF(orientation, unit, size);

  doc.setFontSize(15);

  const title = "Export PDF";
  const headers = [["label", "name"]];

  const data = gridData.map(elt=> [elt.label, elt.name]);

  let content = {
    startY: 50,
    head: headers,
    body: data
  };

  doc.text(title, marginLeft, 40);
  doc.autoTable(content);
  doc.save("report.pdf")

Comment: <div>
        <button onClick={(e) => setExportPDF(e.target.value)}>Generate Report</button>
      </div>

Comment: could you edit the question with all that instead of putting it in the comments?

Answer (score 0):

```js
 import React from 'react';
    import jsPDF from "jspdf";
    import "jspdf-autotable";
    import './App.css';
    
    const App =()=> {
     const [state,setState] =React.useState {
          people: [
            { name: "Keanu Reeves", profession: "Actor" },
            { name: "Lionel Messi", profession: "Football Player" },
            { name: "Cristiano Ronaldo", profession: "Football Player" },
            { name: "Jack Nicklaus", profession: "Golf Player" },
          ]
        }
    
      const exportPDF = () => {
        const unit = "pt";
        const size = "A4"; // Use A1, A2, A3 or A4
        const orientation = "portrait"; // portrait or landscape
    
        const marginLeft = 40;
        const doc = new jsPDF(orientation, unit, size);
    
        doc.setFontSize(15);
    
        const title = "My Awesome Report";
        const headers = [["NAME", "PROFESSION"]];
    
        const data = state?.people?.map(elt=> [elt.name, elt.profession]);
    
        let content = {
          startY: 50,
          head: headers,
          body: data
        };
    
        doc.text(title, marginLeft, 40);
        doc.autoTable(content);
        doc.save("report.pdf")
      }
    
        return (
          <div>
            <button onClick={exportPDF}>Generate Report</button>
          </div>
        );
      
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: `people` variable can be a normal variable instead of a state variable.

Comment: @ManishKumar Yes, it can be but the main concern is to convert his Class component into Functional Component